# Problems with multiple textures in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, textures

Im trying to write a class for loading objects into my program/ The problem is that OpenGL loads only the last texture for all object.

Here is the code:

The game.cpp class:

```
object =  new Object("table.obj", "wood.bmp",0); // a new object - obj file, texture and 
object1 = new Object("aa.obj", "cloth.bmp",1);   // texture number

object->draw();
object1->draw();
```

Object class:

```
AUX_RGBImageRec *texture;

 Object::Object(char* filename, char* texname, int num) {
 tex_num = num;
 is_loaded = false;
.... some vertex stuff here
texture = auxDIBImageLoadA(texname);
}

 void Object::draw() {
if(!is_loaded) {
     loadTexture();
     is_loaded = true;
 }
 ... vertex stuff again
 void Object::loadTexture() {
    GLuint *tex = new GLuint[10];
 unsigned int names[10];
 glGenTextures(1, tex);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[tex_num]);
 cout << tex_num << endl;
// glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3,
         texture->sizeX,
         texture->sizeY,
         0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
         texture->data);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 // free memory
 delete tex;
 cout << tex_num << endl;
  }
```

Comment: Please stop using AUX to load your images. If you are using a tutorial that uses AUX, please stop using that tutorial and [find better ones.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you dynamically allocating the texture ID variable? Why are you deleting it at the end of `loadTexture` when you need it, to actually refer to the texture when drawing? OpenGL will not magically associate textures with geometry itself.

Following changes:

```
- Object::Object(char* filename, char* texname, int num) {
+ Object::Object(char* filename, char* texfilename) {

-     tex_num = num;
     is_loaded = false;
    .... some vertex stuff here
-    texture = auxDIBImageLoadA(texname);
+    loadTexture(texfilename);

}

class Object {
/*...*/
+     GLuint texID;
}

void Object::draw() {
-if(!is_loaded) {
-     loadTexture();
-     is_loaded = true;
- }

+  glBindTexure(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
+  draw_geometry();
}

- void Object::loadTexture() {
+ void Object::loadTexture(char const * const texfilename) {

 -    GLuint *tex = new GLuint[10];
 -    unsigned int names[10];
 -    glGenTextures(1, tex);
 -    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[tex_num]);
 -    cout << tex_num << endl;

 +    glGenTexture(1, &texID);
 +    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
 +    cout << texID << endl;

 +    // Image is a yet to implement class offering image loading
 +    // in a RAII fashion.
 +    Image img = Image::fromFile(texfilename);

 -   // glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
 -    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3,
 -            texture->sizeX,
 -            texture->sizeY,
 -            0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
 -            texture->data);

 +   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, img.alignment());
 +    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
 +            img.glinternalformat(), // don't use a channel count here!
 +            img.width(),
 +            img.height(),
 +            0,
 +            img.glformat(),
 +            img.gltype(),
 +            img.data() );

     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

-     // free memory
-     delete tex;
-     cout << tex_num << endl;
+     cout << texID << endl;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I still need to call if(!is_loaded) { .. block once in draw function, without this textures don't display.

Comment: @DarkSun: Then you're probably creating your "Object" instances before there is a OpenGL context created and activated. In that case on-demand loading of resources in the display function is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now that your first draw() call loaded your texture, you just have to call glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, your_generated_buffer) before each draw.

```
void      Object::draw()
{
       if(!is_loaded)
       {
            loadTexture();
            is_loaded = true;
       }
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texture_buffer);
       // Your vertex things..
}
```

if this->texture_buffer represents your generated texture buffer for example, btw what you are doing is strange, you are allocating a GLuint* array ? I'd rather recommend you this:

```
void Object::loadTexture()
{
     glGenTextures(1, &this->texture_buffer);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texture_buffer);
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3,
                  texture->sizeX,
                  texture->sizeY,
                  0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  texture->data);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

PS: If you want to know why only the last texture is applied, it's because OpenGL works in a way that, he draws what you want him to draw, thanks to the currently activated textures, lights, ... and as your last call to object1->draw(), calls the last loadtexture(), which activates your last texture by calling glBindTexture().